# add header expire for online script in htacess Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, optimization, online-storage

Hi i need to add aa header expiry in my magento site. 
below is the script which needs to be add expiry

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700
>   https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
>   https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js

i have a folowing code in  my htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

Please suggest me how can i add expiry for online scripts Thanks

Comment: You can't. At least not directly. The `Expires*` settings of **your** server got nothing to do with the files delivered by **another** server. You'd need a proxy server between your and the other server to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

As of my findings on your question, It is NOT POSSIBLE and it is not recommended also. Go through this [How can I add expire headers for scripts that are not on my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439042/how-can-i-add-expire-headers-for-scripts-that-are-not-on-my-server)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set expiry headers or any headers to files that are served from a third party. Your options are:

1. Copy those files locally and set your desired headers
2. Keep it as is and ignore any reports saying headers missing or whatever

Only in rare cases I see advantage in using #1. Otherwise, your best bet is to leave it alone.